# What is the naming convention used for overiding file-link.html.twig?

Tags: theming

I have been trying to override file-link.html.twig for a specific content type. I can override it for all but for a specific type I cannot find the corret naming convention. I have twig debug and the like all on but it only suggests **file-link.html.twig**.

My initial thought was:

```
file-link--content-type.html.twig
```

I have tried this and a few others but nothing gets picked up. CAn anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: If Twig debug doesn't show any alternative suggestions then you'll need to implement hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x
(HOOK will be file_link in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Should have said I already tried that and it doesn't show anything that works. Wondering if I have something corrupted so will try a fresh install.

Comment: Can you explain what you tried in the hook? (I meant you will need to use the hook to add your own programatically, in case that wasn't clear)

Comment: Very simply, and to test more than anything else, I did 'function mytheme_theme_suggestions_file_link_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) { dump("FILE LINK ALTER"); }' AND also 'function mytheme_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) { dump("NODE ALTER"); }' - obviously replace mytheme with the real theme name. Just done as a basic test to see if funcion gets called. Nothing so assuming I have issues elsewhere so will reinstall and test again. I have done this before and no issues.

Comment: It'll only get called after a cache clear so that's one thing to consider.

Comment: Yep and am doing cache clears, in my dev envronment using either grunt or `watch -c -n 30 drush cr` or just manually. Nothing worked. However a fresh install an it does so will add modules and configurations in bit by bit, obviously something causing issues I have done. Thanks for the pointers.